# Why does the Dantzig cut require the constraint data to be integral?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

Given the following integer linear program,

> (ILP) $\min c'x$ subject to $Ax \ge b, x \in \mathbb{N}_0$

where all elements of $A$ and $b$ are integral, and assuming its linear-program relaxation (LP) has a non-degenerate optimal solution $x^\mathrm{LP}$ with at least one fractional valued variable, we can formulate the **Dantzig cut** $$\sum_{i\in N}x_i \ge 1$$ where $N$ is the set of nonbasic variables at $x^\mathrm{LP}$. The reason is, since $x^\mathrm{LP}$ is not feasible in (ILP), any optimal solution of (ILP) cannot have all $x_i, x\in N,$ zero; i.e., at least one of $x_i, i\in N$, is strictly positive.

Here is my question: **Where does the condition that $A$ and $b$ are integral come in?** It seems to me that every step of the argument goes through without this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^{LP}$ is not integer, then at least one of the variables $x_i$, for $i \in N$, must be nonzero. Here the condition over $A$ and $b$ plays a central role: given that all coefficients of $A$ and $b$ are integer, it follows that the smallest nonzero value that a variable $x_i$, for $i \in N$, may assume is 1.